# How to call another key from ng-repeat source

Tags: angularjs

Pardon me if the question sounds weird. Suppose I have the following object:

```
// For example purposes, pretend that link gets pushed to $scope.links 5 times.
var link = {
    name: "name",
    description: "description",
    members: [{
         memname: "member name"
    }],
    active: true
}

$scope.links.push(link);
```

...and I used $scope.links as follows

```
<li ng-repeat="item in links">
    <li ng-repeat = "member in item.members">
    ...
    </li>
</li>
```

...and inside the list with `member in item.members`, I want to use `link.active` for `ng-show`. Is it possible to do so?

Something like:

`<li ng-repeat="member in item.members" ng-show="item.active">`.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: In the way you have written it, it should work fine... What is the problem ?

Comment: Of course it will work. `ng-repeat` creates his own scope so you could even init custom variable on the first ng-repeat and use it with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Created Snippet for you .

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.links = [{
    'name': "name",
    'description': "description",
    'members': [{
         'memname': "member name"
    },{
         'memname': "member name 2"
    }],
    'active': true
},{
    'name': "name 2",
    'description': "description",
    'members': [{
         'memname': "member name"
    },{
         'memname': "member name 2"
    }],
    'active': false
}]

//$scope.links.push(link);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in links" ng-show="item.active == true">
         {{item.name}}
         <ul >
            <li ng-repeat = "member in item.members" >
               {{member.memname}}
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.